# Why does Method Overriding does not work on Primitives-Wrapper as well as Super-Subclasses parameters but throws?

Tags: java, overriding

I have tested following

```
class raexception extends Exception{

}
class baexception extends raexception{

}

interface ram{
  public void miya(float a) throws raexception;
}
public class Classy implements ram{
  @Override
  public void miya(Float a) throws baexception {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
  } 
}
```

In above use case,

1. I can give Subclass in Throws section
2. In parameters, I am not allowed to give either Wrapper class or Subclass.

**Question**: 
Is this understanding correct? if yes, is there any specific reason that  throws allowed with subclass but in method parameter subclass is not allowed?

Comment: You should, however, follow the Java Naming Conventions. Class names are always written in PascalCase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. A subclass can also be used in the return type. For the parameters, *superclasses* can be used, not subclasses.

Whatever method you are overriding, you are kind of "fulfilling a requirement", aren't you? In this case, the interface requires to have a method called `miya` that takes in a `float` and might throw a `raexception`. *You can fulfil this in more than one way.*

A method called `miya` that takes in a `float` but throws a `baexception` fulfils the requirement. Why? You can think of it like this: the callers of the method expects your method to throw a `raexception`, so they are able to handle a `raexception`. Now, are they able to handle a `baexception`? Of course they are! `baexception` is a subclass of `raexception`.

You can use the same chain of reasoning to figure out why you can use superclasses in parameter types, and why you can use subclasses in return types.

Regarding wrapper types, it's just that when a primitive argument is passed to a wrapper type, it has to boxed. The callers of your method expects to only put primitive arguments into your method, not boxing. You should think of `float` and `Float` as two separate types. The reason why you can normally convert between them in an assignment context is because the compiler is being nice.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation must be compatible with the definition in the interface.

As `baexception` is a subclass of `raexception`, not problem: the implementation can throw any `baexception`: it is also an `raexception`.

You cannot implement the method with a `Float` argument because the interface specifies a `float`. The method in the class does not implement the one in the interface.

I guess the compiler could generate a second method implementing `miya(float a)` and generate the code to embox the argument, but what would happen if a subclass overrides it? or both methods?